# Joining two different queries under one answer

Tags: sql, combinations

I have two different queries that have produced the correct result, but I would like to have them produce the answer out in one table. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT count(distinct ID) as NoOfEmployees
FROM Table_Name
WHERE date<= '2012-05-31';

select count(subA.ID) as EmployeesChanged from (
SELECT A.ID 
FROM Table_Name A 
WHERE A.date < '2012-06-01' 
GROUP BY 1 
HAVING COUNT(A.Service_type) > 1 ) subA
```

Currently I have the following output:

```
Number of Employees
x
```

```
Employees Changed
x
```

How do I make it

```
Number of Employees |  Employees Changed  | (Number of employees - number changed)
x                   |             x       |            x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what database do you use. But for some databases you can try:

```
select q1.Value, q2.Value, q1.Value - q2.Value from
  (SELECT count(distinct ID) as Value FROM Table_Name 
    WHERE date<= '2012-05-31') q1,
  (select count(subA.ID) as Value from 
      ( SELECT A.ID FROM Table_Name A 
        WHERE A.date < '2012-06-01' GROUP BY 1 
        HAVING COUNT(A.Service_type) > 1 ) subA) q2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, a.NoOfEmployees - b.EmployeesChanged
FROM
(
    SELECT count(distinct ID) as NoOfEmployees
    FROM Table_Name
    WHERE date<= '2012-05-31'
) a
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT count(subA.ID) as EmployeesChanged 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT A.ID 
        FROM Table_Name A 
        WHERE A.date < '2012-06-01' 
        GROUP BY 1 
        HAVING COUNT(A.Service_type) > 1 
    ) subA
) b
```

**Edit:**

You might be able to greatly optimize your query by using conditional aggregation instead of executing two separate queries:

```
SELECT a.NoOfEmployees, a.EmployeesChanged, a.NoOfEmployees - a.EmployeesChanged
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN date <= '2012-05-31' THEN ID END) as NoOfEmployees,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN date < '2012-06-01' AND COUNT(Service_type) > 1 THEN ID END) AS EmployeesChanged
    FROM Table_Name
    GROUP BY ID
) a
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What does a.* mean exactly? Is that the results from query a?

Comment: @user1519731, yes. Since there is only one column in the selection, it's more concise to just use the wildcard `*`.

Answer (score 0):

If date<= '2012-05-31' is the same as A.date < '2012-06-01'  ?

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS NoOfEmployees,
SUM(CASE WHEN STCount > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as HasChange,
SUM(CASE WHEN STCount = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NoChange
FROM 
  (SELECT ID,
  COUNT(A.Service_type) STCount
  FROM Table_Name
  WHERE date<= '2012-05-31'
  GROUP BY ID) AS Data
```